# Doubts about canvas layer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm learning the technology of canvas. I've seen some codes, such as drawing a national map or others. They all have one thing in common, that is, there are multiple layers, but only one layer is displayed. I don't understand what kind of use hidden layers need to be drawn and used

Comment: Can you share an example showing this behavior?

Comment: Canvas doesn't really have layers. You can get started by reading the basic canvas documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API